# Writing a function to change values of a particular column/variable

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm working with multiple CSVs and one of the columns/variable is "Country" that contains the full name of the 30 countries that are all the same for other CSVs as well. I'm looking for a way to abbreviate the country's full name to 3-letters (eg. Canada to CAN, France to FRA, Australia to AUS, etc). Because of the multiple CSVs, I'd thought it'd be more efficient to write a function for this rather than using gsub() for those 20 countries for each CSV which seems a bit tedious.

I've only gotten this far with this script and I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed further:

```
import_country_data_year <- function(filename) {
country_data_year <- read_csv(filename)
}
```

A solution I've tried is writing an if statement, but doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You might want to load the countrycode package so that you can use the standard ISO alpha-3 codes that already exist for each country. You could then use `countrycode(FULL_COUNTRY_NAME, origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')`

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give that a try. But is there a way to write a function for this for future reference?

Comment: Sure you could get the first three letters using `substr(COUNTRY_NAME, 1, 3)`, but this will potentially lead to conflicts like Australia / Austria.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just one more question. Similarly to this, but for NBA data there are certain teams like Golden State, New Orleans, or New York where the abbreviated would be GSW, NOP and NYK where substring of the first three letters wouldn't work. Any suggestions on this as well?

Comment: Make a table like `lookup <- data.frame(fullname = c("Golden State", "New Orleans"), abbrev = c("GSW", "NOP"))` and then use `my_data %>% dplyr::left_join(lookup)` to add the column that's missing from the main table.